# CSV-Parser doesn't seem to parse line break data properly

Tags: javascript, csv

Yes, I know I should have better data, and if nothing works I will go about fixing my data, but I was wondering if there was any way I could get csv-parser parser to parse

```
"United States of
America",140640,17987,2398,286,Local transmission,0
```

Into

```
{
Country: United States of America
... blah blah
... blah blah
... blah blah
... blah blah
}

fs.createReadStream("./csv/03312020.csv")
    .pipe(
        csv([
            "Country",
            "Total",
            "TotalNew"
        ])
    )
    .on("data", row => {
        console.log(row.Country);
        let result = contains(row.Country);
        if (result !== undefined) {
            row.Date = today;
            row.id = result + "-" + today;
            if (db.dates.get(row.id) === undefined) db.dates.create(row);
        }
    })
    .on("end", () => {
        console.log("CSV file successfully processed for", today);
    });
```

I thought the csv-parser would see that there is a quotation mark and wrap that as one "column" but apparently it doesn't. Is there a better way to parse this data other than reparsing my CSV file itself?

Comment: `Country: United States of America` ignoring the fact that's not valid syntax, it _should_ be `Country: 'United States of\nAmerica'` in order for your handler to find a match.

Comment: I'm using a csv-pdf scraper, the first "block of code" represents what is coming out of the scraper

Comment: What you can do is split that file into lines, then join the lines that have an odd number of " characters. After that you can run the new file through your parser like before.

Comment: @zoran404 if you write that into an answer I'll accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is split that file into lines, then join the lines that have an odd number of " characters.

My script also handles the case where the \n character appears multiple times in a single row of data.
This is based on the fact that only the first and the last line of a multi-line row will have an odd number of " characters.

You can reformat your file using my script and then feed it into your csv parser.

```js
const example1 = `"United States of
America",140640,17987,2398,286,Local transmission,0`;

console.log(reformatCsv(example1));

const example2 = `"United States of
America",140640,17987,2398,286,"Local
transmission",0`;

console.log(reformatCsv(example2));


// @param file: string
function reformatCsv(file)
{
    const lines = file.split('\n');

    let reformattedRows = [];

    const parts = [];

    for (const line of lines)
    {
        const quoteMatches = line.match(/"/g);
        const isEvenNumberOfQuotes = !quoteMatches || quoteMatches.length % 2 == 0;
        const noPartialRowsYet = !parts.length;

        if (noPartialRowsYet)
        {
            if (isEvenNumberOfQuotes) // normal row
            {
                reformattedRows.push(line);
            }
            else // this is a partial row
            {
                parts.push(line);
            }
        }
        else // continuation of a partial row
        {
            parts.push(line);
            if (!isEvenNumberOfQuotes) // we got all of the parts
            {
                // join the parts
                // I replace \n with a space character, but you don't have to
                reformattedRows.push(parts.join(' '));
            }
        }
    }

    return reformattedRows.join('\n');
}
```